# Remove odd spacing between HTML/CSS tiles

Tags: html, css, display

Here is a screenshot of what the spacing looks like, I'm looking for just a display mode to make everything just fit where they can without new lines being made.
[image]

This is what it looks like but ideally I would like there to be no gap on the left side

I'm just looking for a display setting to fix the problem (ex. display: whatever ; )

Any help is appreciated ;D

Comment: Could you provide a JSFiddle so we can see the code you are trying...nobody on here is going to re-write your layout for you.  Thanks :)

Comment: I didn't think it would be needed, i just added that i just wanted a display setting for the whole file to use so it looks nicer.

Comment: You should be able to use `display: inline-block`

Comment: create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example: http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve

Comment: @Alex Thanks you fixed my problem looks so much better now :D

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you're using **Bootstrap** you can make the top row of panels fit within a

```
<div class="row">
```

The next row that you want needs to be inside another "row" class. The code should look something like this:

```
<div class="row">
  <div id="one" class="col-sm-2 panel panel-default">
    <div id="oskartommy"></div>
  </div>
  <div id="two" class="col-sm-2 panel panel-default">
    <div id="rorum"></div>
  </div>
  <div id="three" class="col-sm-2 panel panel-default">
    <div id="itsaka"></div>
  </div>
  <div id="four" class="col-sm-2 panel panel-default">
    <div id="mylittle"></div>
  </div>
  <div id="four" class="col-sm-2 panel panel-default">
    <div id="meow"></div>
  </div>
  <div id="six" class="col-sm-2 panel panel-default">
    <div id="lil_toxic"></div>
  </div>
</div>

<div class="row">
  <div id="one" class="col-sm-2 panel panel-default">
    <div id="joa"></div>
  </div>
  <div id="two" class="col-sm-2 panel panel-default">
    <div id="oskatommy"></div>
  </div>
  <div id="three" class="col-sm-2 panel panel-default">
    <div id="bausz"></div>
  </div>
  <div id="four" class="col-sm-2 panel panel-default">
    <div id="bntlol"></div>
  </div>
  <div id="four" class="col-sm-2 panel panel-default">
    <div id="flom"></div>
  </div>
  <div id="six" class="col-sm-2 panel panel-default">
    <div id="m0ew_tv"></div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Try working with something like that to organize your panels.  I made all the columns 2 column width just to be evenly spaced, but you can rearrange that however you need using a 12 column responsive grid system.